# Looking for a piece of code working in IE 10 and Firefox loading xml on local hard-drive

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer-10

This is my working piece of code for IE<10, FF and Safari.

```
var xmlDoc;
function importXML(xmlfile)
{
var element; 
var xmlloaded = false;

    try
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", xmlfile, false);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        var ie = (typeof window.ActiveXObject != 'undefined');

        if (ie)
        {
            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            while(xmlDoc.readyState != 4) {};
```

IE10 give me error in the following line of code: doesn't support load

```
            xmlDoc.load(xmlfile);
            element = xmlDoc.documentElement;
            xmlloaded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
            xmlDoc.onload = element = xmlDoc.documentElement;
            xmlDoc.load(xmlfile);
            xmlloaded = true;
        }
    }

    if (!xmlloaded)
    {
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
        xmlhttp.send("");
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        element = xmlDoc.documentElement;
        xmlloaded = true;
    }
}
```

I need this to work with IE 10 too.
I know the solution is here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/19/xmlhttprequest-responsexml-in-ie10-release-preview.aspx because in another question on stackvoerflow a user said he found a solution there but he didn't wrote the mod.
I didn't write myself the above code and I'm a beginner so I don't know how to operate.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't access the local file system for security reasons. If you have access to the required file and a server of some type, put the file on the server and access it from there using a URL.

Comment: Do you mean that for a new security reason this happens in IE10 and above? In Safari, FF (both newest versions) and IE<10 this works! I have an online xml viewer and another one offline.